# What could cause std::condition_variable notify_all to be very slow (>2ms)?

Tags: c++, linux, performance, condition-variable

I've got a fairly large linux x64 system with lots of threads and heavy resource usage. We recently discovered that, occasionally, notify_all() was taking upward of 2ms, and was frequently taking on the order of 100us. In toy examples on the same system, it reliably takes < 1us. We're measuring in a really simple way, calling std::chrono:high_resolution_clock::now() immediately before and after the call to notify_all(). What could be causing this multiple order of magnitude discrepancy? I was under the impression that notify was extremely cheap & fast.

Comment: The Linux kernel is not a realtime OS. Could be many factors, thread context switching taking a long time, or a bunch of I/O needing to be flushed. You have no performance guarantees for anything, with the stock Linux kernel.

Comment: measurement of order of `us` are not very reliable. At that order you mostly measure system noise.

Comment: There's also the issue that `notify_all` could be quite cheap, but since you have "lots of threads" the newly notified threads might be given scheduling priority, and the thread that called `notify_all` might not be given a core to run on for a little while. Keep in mind, [`std::chrono:high_resolution_clock` has no consistent implementation](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/high_resolution_clock#Notes), but in both implementations, it's not tracking CPU time in the current thread, it's tracking the passage of wall-clock time, so your thread might just be snoozed by the scheduler.